# Почему пишет "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Tags: javascript

Вот мой код JS:

```
function submit() {
window.alert("PRIVET");
};
var eqr = document.getElementById(address);
eqr.addEventListener('click' , submit);
```

И вот мой HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="address"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128853/discussion-on-question-by-david-shahmatov---cannot-read-property-ad).

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавь `''` вокруг address:

   ```
   var eqr = document.getElementById('address');
   ```
2. Добавь в начале файла 'use strict', во избежание подобных ошибок. Вместо строки с id для поиска, была передана переменная address. Такой переменной нет и браузер создал ее налету, в ней лежит undefined. По итогу браузер подставил в поиск undefined, ничего не нашел и вернул null как результат:

   ```
   // ищем элемент с id = undefined
   var eqr = document.getElementById(address);
   ```

'use strict' - строгий режим, при котором подобные ошибки сразу всплывают, браузер не пытается создавать неявно переменные, прописать его нужно в самом начале скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали address без кавычек, поэтому можно сказать, что вы обращаетесь к переменной address. Если вам нужен именно id address, тогда надо написать его в кавычках.

И на данный момент для getElementById появилась более современная замена querySelector. `document.querySelector("#address")`, то есть вместо названия id вы пишите селектор как в css.